# Config server with Vault backend - fetch secrets from multiple paths

Tags: hashicorp-vault, spring-cloud-config-server, spring-vault, spring-cloud-vault-config

We are using config server with Vault backend to fetch application secrets.
Config server project is using `spring-vault-core` dependency and `spring-vault-dependencies` dependency management for Vault.

Vault related config in application yml file is as follows:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        vault:
          order: 0
          uri: <complete URI>
          connection-timeout: 5000
          read-timeout: 15000
          kvVersion: 2
          backend: secret
          defaultKey: config
```

This works fine and fetches me the Vault secrets in `secret/config`.

I am unable to add secret fetching from multiple paths in Vault (`secret/config` + `secret/customFolder`). I have tried adding comma separated application-name etc as suggested across various posts but does not work. Has anyone tried something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look to the `composite` profile.

There are a lot of additional questions - what exactly you are trying to do, and why do you want to have this?

For us, for example, it was important to split infra services configurations and also split, actually, microservices configurations by itself. And, important requirement, to be able to "overwrite" it (in case of migrations, for instance).

We have achieve that with two things:

- on config server side we are using `composite` configuration (with exactly the same `type` and `uri`, but little bit different `backend` and `keys`),
- on config client's side we are specifying several values for `spring.cloud.config.name` property (coma separated list).

Comment: Thanks @Stepan this worked. In my case, I am trying to put a common set of secrets in a Secrets path and a service specific ones in another. This is where I had the requirement of accessing multiple paths

Comment: can you please provide the configuration? i am not able to solve the problem